# IMGUR API Мультизагрузка

Tags: javascript, api

Работаю по API.
Пытаюсь загрузить на IMGUR изображения пачкой.
Выбираются 2 изображения, но загружается только одно.
Как исправить?

````
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/U7afLiO.png" id="img" height="200px">
   <br />
   <input type="file" multiple  id="file">
   <br />
   <strong>
       <p id="url"></p>
   </strong>

   <script>
       const file = document.getElementById("file")
       const img = document.getElementById("img")
       const url = document.getElementById("url")
       file.addEventListener("change", ev => {
           const formdata = new FormData()
           formdata.append("image", ev.target.files[0])
           fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/", {
               method: "post",
               headers: {
                   Authorization: "Client-ID 6db47bd7029562d"
               },
               body: formdata
           }).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
               img.src = data.data.link
               url.innerText = data.data.link
           })
       })
     
     var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Client-ID 6db47bd7029562d");

var requestOptions = {
 method: 'GET',
 headers: myHeaders,
 redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/album/ryQCmre", requestOptions)
 .then(response => response.text())
 .then(result => console.log(result))
 .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
     
     
   </script>```
````